# Task :expo-location:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, compiler-errors, expo

I merge work of my coworker and even after seeing all the stackOverflow/github/... solution i'm still stuck with this trouble.
My error is like this (it's with Expo but the error can change to expo-permission error or other too)

```
> Task :expo-location:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
C:\Users\flori\work\epitech\eip\tmp\app-takotak\TakOTak\node_modules\expo-location\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\location\LocationModule.java:520: error: cannot find symbol
    return mPermissionsManager == null || !mPermissionsManager.hasGrantedPermissions(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION);
                                                                                                        ^
  symbol:   variable ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
  location: class permission
Note: C:\Users\flori\work\epitech\eip\tmp\app-takotak\TakOTak\node_modules\expo-location\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\location\taskConsumers\GeofencingTaskConsumer.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error

> Task :expo-location:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':expo-location:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 11s
441 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 439 up-to-date
<-------------> 0% WAITING
> IDLE
> IDLE
> IDLE
> IDLE
```

My package json is like this:

```
{
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "resources/fonts"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "~1.12.0",
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^2.0.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps": "^8.1.0",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.3.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.10",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.12.8",
    "expo": "^40.0.0",
    "expo-facebook": "~9.1.0",
    "expo-font": "~8.4.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.8.1",
    "expo-updates": "~0.4.1",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.6",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.4",
    "react-native-clear-cache": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-eject": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.8.0",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.16.3",
    "react-native-hr": "^1.1.4",
    "react-native-icon-badge": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-maps": "0.27.1",
    "react-native-multiple-select-list": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.5.0",
    "react-native-places-input": "^1.1.7",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area": "^0.5.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.9",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.16.1",
    "react-native-slider": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-status-bar-height": "^2.6.0",
    "react-native-swipe-cards-deck": "^0.2.14",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.15.2",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.12.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.0",
    "reanimated-bottom-sheet": "^1.0.0-alpha.22",
    "socket.io-client": "^3.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
    "babel-jest": "~25.2.6",
    "jest": "~25.2.6",
    "react-test-renderer": "~16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

The content of my gradle-wrapper-properties:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.6.1-bin.zip
```

I'm working with:

- Nodejs --> v14.15.4
- Window 10
- Android Sdk 29/28

What i've already try:

- Change my gradle properties
- delete node_modules/package-lock.json 'x' times
- Update Expo/React Native
- Use Jetifier

Knowing that the project is functional with my coworkers working on Android

If you need more information let me know...

Thanks

Comment: Got the same error on the mac and working building for android.

Comment: I've got it fix with upgrating android SDK and by taking the android folder from a brand new project (some modification, like names need to be done in the folder).

Comment: hi Florian Frevol plese give us more imformation for fixing this bug

Comment: @FlorianFrevol please give us more context on the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the JDK correctly installed. In my case, it couldn't find the `jlink` executable in the java path.

Answer (score 0):

I am on Linux Fedora and got the same problem, and I managed to solve this issue by doing:

1. Install Missing jlink: It seems that the jlink utility is missing or not installed correctly. To install it, you can use your system's package manager:

> sudo dnf install java-17-openjdk-devel

2. Set Java Home: Ensure that your Java environment variables are correctly configured. You can add the following line to your shell profile (e.g., .bashrc, .zshrc) to set the JAVA_HOME variable:

> export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-17.0.8.0.7-1.fc38.x86_64

3. Rebuilding again.

I hope it helps others.